# CKEditor File Upload & Browser

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using version 3.4.1, but of course it doesn't come with the file browser like the FCKeditor did.

I'm looking for a basic asp image uploader script I can use and also wanted to run the procedure by someone who knows about this.

My research tells me I need to modify the config.js file to add: *config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '../filename';* within the function there already.

Obviously 'filename' will be my uploader script when I get it.

Can someone point me in the right direction and whether it's correct to add the URL as above to config.js when i get it?

I can find PHP scrips of course, but no asp as yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples about how to integrate your own file manager in the docs: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_%28Uploader%29/Custom_File_Browser

It's a simple matter of replacing the little php blocks with asp.

An example template for a php file uploader is here: http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2009/12/using-your-own-uploader-in-ckeditor.html